# Download an ancient Digital Elevation Model (DEM)

Tags: data-request

I need an ancient DEM. My research is focus on Spain and the most important characteristic of the DEM is the year. The resolution is not such important as the year. Do you know where I can download it on free?

Comment: What do you mean by *ancient*? In general, DEM are obtained using *modern* techniques, from wikipedia ["The DEM could be acquired through techniques such as photogrammetry, lidar, IfSAR, land surveying, etc. (Li et al. 2005)."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_elevation_model#Types_of_DEM) and from the last 40/50 years you will not see many changes (except that related with the accuracy of the sensors to retrieve the elevation data). It would be helpful if you could clarify your question a little bit.

Comment: I need a old DEM, because my research is focus in a place where in the last 30 years has been made land movements, in this way a current DEM are not useful for my.  To get an idea, I have an ortophoto of 1956, but maybe I can not get a DEM from this period.

Comment: Maybe you can try the Instituto GeoMinero (http://info.igme.es/catalogo/?tab=2). In general, these datasets are quite expensive and most of them with very high resolution are made for military/scientific purposes on small areas so are not so open. Data retrieved from polar satellites are obtained in missions (e.g., [SRTM](http://www.cgiar-csi.org/data/srtm-90m-digital-elevation-database-v4-1)) and not regularly and the resolution maybe is not enough for waht you are looking for. Maybe I'm wrong but I think you will not be lucky :-(